# Best way to do 3d printer nozzle animation

Tags: animation, modifiers

[image]

This is the result I'm trying to achieve. The blue part is a mesh object. I did this using a boolean modifier but that makes the material act weird and it doesn't look right in the video.

I have tried using bevel geometry on a curve but that fails when I try to vary the thickness.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I wonder why the bevelled curve approach is failing you..

Answer (score 9):

If you want a full profile, you could use the native bevel and mapping of an ordinary straight Bezier curve.

You could make the ink first, setting the radii of its control points manually to get the right shape, and keyframe the mapping.

These settings seem reasonable:

[image]

For an exact fit, you *could* then, as here, construct the nozzle from the ink (converting to a mesh, cutting in half, flipping the normals, extruding and scaling) but there would be no harm in a slight intersection, it's all hidden.

[image]

For a flat front, you could use a custom-made semicircular profile for the curve. This one was converted to a curve from a  mesh-circle, cut in half and bevelled to get a slight meniscus...

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Robin, I'd try and do it this way again. I am very new, so I might be missing some things

Comment: I am, very stuck actually. Your beveled spline looks very different from mine. Yours has segments and looks like a mesh object. Mine only shows the control points of the bezier curve.

Comment: Just figured it out, you just have your wireframe overlay on. I think this would help a bit. I'd give it another shot.

Edit: that did work and I got the perfect shape of the nozzle, but the problem with the material still persists. Material changes shade slightly as I vary the start or end property of the bevel. I'd keep working on it.

Comment: Hi @Viput! The radius is linearly interpolated between control points, so where there is a sharp change, you have to put in more of them. Shading to do with normals. Again, probably placement of control points. Late here.. share if you like, I'll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: Have a good night. It's 4am for me too. Thanks a lot for your help. I'd probably bother you again in the day.

Answer (score 7):

Try it with a shader. Make an object that fits the gap perfectly (just duplicate the inner vertices) and give it a texture mixing between Transparent BSDF and whatever else you want. Here's a setup that would work well, you can just change the second value on the Add node to move it up and down:
[image]

Comment: This is a pretty good solution, near perfect for what I want, is there a way to make the white part transparent though?

Comment: Sure is- stick that color ramp into a mix shader- ramp color to Factor. Change the blue to Black. Input 1, blue, input 2, transparent BSDF.